# Want to get the details of the user(member) after login successfully in xamarin forms

Tags: web-services, xamarin.forms, c#-6.0

my question is how to pass username and password from the C# client(xamarin forms) to server's API? if details are correct then the client will get whole product list from webapi(URL).and bind all the details to a listview.I want to get the member details after the success of response code.

the client will send username password from login page to server's API. if server's webapi check whether the details matched with the database, if not, don't let it get product list.

here is the code in loginservices for login(xamarin forms)

---

public  async Task GetData(string username,string password)

```
    {
        //string detail = new UserDetails();
        UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails();
       // List<UserDetails> detail = new List<UserDetails>();
        try
        {
            var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Username", username));
            values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", password));
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("nl-NL"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var response = await client.PostAsync("http://192.168.1.50/Accounts/Authenticate", content);
                return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;




            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

here is the code for web api---

public async Task ValidateUser([FromBody] Credentials credentials)
        {

```
        using (DemoAPPEntities entities = new DemoAPPEntities())
        {
            var result = await entities.MemberDetails.Where(x => x.UserName == credentials.UserName && x.Password == credentials.Password).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

            if (result == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(entities.MemberDetails);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried seeing what's coming in `response.Content` ?

Comment: would you please ellabarote ? where  should I write this code?

Comment: from the above code i am just validating user name and password  from api...

Comment: Instead of returning `response.IsSuccessStatus` , make a breakline and see what's coming in `response.Content`

Comment: {StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 01 Jan 2018 05:43:44 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Content-Length: 283
}}

Comment: response.content

Comment: the problem is that if I am going to use response.content- then I have to use Task<string> and if I am doing so then It's redirecting me to the next page after login, don't return false if the credential is not matched.

Comment: in Task<bool> it doesn't allow me to use response.content.? what to do or not? I am totally confused and stuck in this code from last 10 days.